# Pitch detection doesn't work well, all above 23000

Tags: java, pitch

I'm writing a program that in part of it, it should detect pitch. In the program, I should choose an audio file from my computer and I use YIN from [here](https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP/blob/2d421826032bccacdddcc3fc2c23524f4d776103/TarsosDSP/src/main/java/be/hogent/tarsos/dsp/pitch/Yin.java) to detect the Pitch.

My problem is that when I choose the audio file , all of my pitches (that I calculate for each frame) are above 23000Hz! I have tested it also with FFT. 
The only condition that it works well is with a file that I record myself and I play note E(Mi) for some seconds with my violin.

Comment: [This is 3 000 Hz above the high end of the human hearing range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearing_range); assuming you can hear the sound, something's clearly up.

Comment: Yes, I know. While what I choose is an audio file (that I can hear), It shows 23,000 Hz!

Comment: That was more of a note to future readers.